# Bind Two List With Column Match

Tags: c#, linq

I've two list of items as follows:

```
List A
Id Hobbies      Category
1  Dance        A
1  Reading Book A
2  Reading Book A
2  Gardening    A

List B
Id ContactNo
1  123456
1  7891011
2  121314
2  151617
```

What I am trying is simple, just to get the below output:

```
Id Hobbies      ContactNo
1  Dance        123456
   Reading Book 7891011

2  Reading Book 121314
   Gardening    151617
```

Tried the following but it gave me this exception - **DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input**

```
 aLst = (from c in Hobbies
         join d in Contact on c.Id equals d.Id
         where c.Category == "A"
         select new Model
         {
            Id = c.Id,
            AllHobbies = c.Hobbies.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList(),
            AllContacts = c.ContactNo.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList(),
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more, whats your matching criteria here, id? if so in list type C both hobbies and Contacts are a list type of string and select needs to be group by id.

Comment: It's not "simple", it's "simplistic"; perhaps overly so because it relies on the order of input data. If the order changes, the output doesn't work any more, which is very risky

Comment: I tried the below solution provided by one of the stackoverflow user but failed. Any better way to implement @Caius Jard?

Comment: Can you adjust your "expected output" so that it's "JSON flavored"? I can't quite tell what data structure you're requesting/whether you want objects or strings etc. Putting out some pseudo-JSON will help clear all that up. Example: `{ id: 1, data: [{hobby: dance, contact: 123456},{hobby: reading, contact:7891011}]}`

Comment: These are just list of string @Caius Jard. Yes, that's the data structure you provided.

Comment: I got a solution @Caius Jard. It isn't that efficient but serves my purpose, will be sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to group the hobbies and contacts first, then combine them:

```
var groupedHobbies = from h in Hobbies
                     group h by h.ID;
var groupedContacts = from c in Contact
                      group c by c.ID;

var ans = (from hg in groupedHobbies
           join cg in groupedContacts on hg.Key equals cg.Key into cgj
           from cg in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {
               ID = hg.Key,
               Hobbies = hg.Select(h => h.Hobbies).ToList(),
               ContactNos = cg != null ? cg.Select(c => c.ContactNo).ToList() : Enumerable.Empty<string>()
           })
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use group join and i am filtering Hobbies with "A" category before join.

```
aLst = (from c in Hobbies.Where(x=>x.Category=="A").Select(x=>x).ToList()
             join d in Contact on c.Id equals d.Id into grp
             select new Model
             {
                Id = c.Id,
                AllHobbies = grp.Select(c => c.Hobbies).ToList(),
                AllContacts = grp.Select(c => c.ContactNo).ToList(),
             }).ToList();
```

> for your reference:

[group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Comment: Actually it didn't work as expected @Irfan Shaikh. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the appropriate classes for the above data:

```cs
public class Hobbies
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Hobby { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

Please choose one of the below approaches:

```cs
var result = hobbies
    .Where(h => h.Category == "A") // you can apply filtering for a Category here
    .GroupJoin(contacts, 
    hobby => hobby.Id,
    contact => contact.Id, (hobby, contact) => new
{
    Id = hobby.Id,
    Hobby = hobby.Hobby,
    Contacts = contact.Select(c => c.ContactNo)
});
```

OR

```cs
var result = hobbies
    .Where(h => h.Category == "A") // you can apply filtering for a Category here
    .Join(contacts, h => h.Id, c => c.Id,
    (h,c) => new {h.Id, Hobby = h.Hobby, ContactNo = c.ContactNo})
    .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Id = grp.Key, // this Id is the same for both Hobby and Contact
        HobbieContacts = grp.Select(i => new
        {
            ContactNo = i.ContactNo,
            Hobby = i.Hobby
        })
    });
```

---

Please note that I've used `anonymous types in the above examples for demonstration. However, my personal advice would be to use real classes instead.